# Evaluating a function at a point in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to code various optimisation methods, as a way of revising. I want to be able to use SymPy to evaluate a function with an arbitrary number of variables at a given point, where the co-ordinates of the point are stored in an array.

For example, I'd like to evaluate `f(x,y) = 3*x**2 - 2*x*y + y**2 + 4*x + 3*y` at the point `b = [1,2]`. But I'd really like a general way of doing it, that can handle a function with any number of variables and an appropriate length array as the point to be evaluated as, so `sympy.evalf(f, subs = {foo})` isn't really very useful.

Comment: Could you just use map() ? http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map

Comment: http://Whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Welcome to SO! Posting code and some specifics of what you have tried is recommended here, please read the FAQ and hopefully you can get better answers!

Comment: Map looks promising initially, but I don't think it's relevant, sadly - it evaluates a function for several specific values of the arguments. What I want to do is evaluate a SymPy expression at one general multivariate point. Thanks for linking it though, I'd not come across it before and I'm sure it'll be useful in future.

I've had a look through the SymPy documentation, mostly the numerical evaluation and algebra sections, but not found anything useful. This surprises me somewhat, as I feel it's the kind of thing that would be wanted quite often.

Comment: If all your expressions are polynomials, you can also try Poly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are working with SymPy expression trees, not functions. On any expression you can do:

```
>>> vars = sorted(expression.free_symbols)
>>> evaluated = expression.subs(*zip(vars, your_values))
```

Comment: Thanks very much - where can I find the documentation on those commands? I'd rather understand what they do rather than just copy verbatim without understanding!

Comment: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/basic_operations.html

Answer (score 1):

I would also expect this to be easier to do, but here's a good workaround:

If you know the symbol names (`'x'`,`'y'`, e.g.), you can create a `dict` on the fly using `zip`:

```
fvars = sympy.symbols('x, y') #these probably already exist, use: fvars = [x,y]

b = [1,2]
sympy.evalf(f, subs = dict(zip(fvars,b)))
```

Comment: `map(sympy.Symbol,['x','y'])` can be written as `symbols('x, y')`

Comment: If you got the 'not callable' error you probably forgot the "s": symbols('x y').

Answer (score 1):

`lambdify` is a good option to generate a Python-callable function.

An example, assuming you have a function `f` and the symbols `x` and `y`:

```
from sympy import lambdify
import numpy as np

callable_fct = lambdify((x, y), f)
xn = np.arange(0, 2, 0.1)
yn = 3
print(callable_fct(xn, yn))
```