# Python can't evaluate derivatives at a point

Tags: python, sympy

I use Jupyter Notebook. How come this does not work when I want to evaluate the partial derivative at the point P?

```
from sympy import *
P = (-3,-2)
def f(x,y):
    return x**3+3*x**2-9*x+y**3-12*y
def f_x(x,y):
    return diff(f(x,y), x)
```

When I type f(P[0],P[1]), I get the answer 43.

When I type f_x(x,y), I get the derivative of f wrt. x

Then, when I type f_x(P[0],P[1]), I get this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-2-2afed429d2a2> in <module>
      7     return diff(f(x,y), x)
      8 
----> 9 f_x(P[0],P[1])

<ipython-input-2-2afed429d2a2> in f_x(x, y)
      5     return x**3+3*x**2-9*x+y**3-12*y
      6 def f_x(x,y):
----> 7     return diff(f(x,y), x)
      8 
      9 f_x(P[0],P[1])

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\function.py in diff(f,
*symbols, **kwargs)    2503         return f.diff(*symbols, **kwargs)    2504     kwargs.setdefault('evaluate', True)
-> 2505     return _derivative_dispatch(f, *symbols, **kwargs)    2506     2507 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\function.py in
_derivative_dispatch(expr, *variables, **kwargs)    1945         from sympy.tensor.array.array_derivatives import ArrayDerivative    1946    return ArrayDerivative(expr, *variables, **kwargs)
-> 1947     return Derivative(expr, *variables, **kwargs)    1948     1949 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\function.py in __new__(cls, expr, *variables, **kwargs)    1312             if isinstance(v, Integer):    1313                 if i == 0:
-> 1314                     raise ValueError("First variable cannot be a number: %i" % v)    1315                 count = v    1316           prev, prevcount = variable_count[-1]

ValueError: First variable cannot be a number: -3
```

Comment: not a [mre] - include how you exactly call then and provide the `diff` function as well

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "some error saying I can't type numbers in my function"? What's the full error message?

Comment: Have you tried following through the [official Sympy tutorial](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/index.html)? Or does [this previous Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478449/evaluating-a-function-at-a-point-in-sympy) answer your question?

Comment: You should use a [`sympy.Symbol("x")`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#id21) rather than just `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing:

`f_x(P[0], P[1])` becomes

`f_x(-3, -2)` becomes

`diff(f(-3, -2), -3)` becomes

`diff(43, -3)` which gives an error: you can't calculate the derivative of the constant function `43` towards a number (`-3`).

In sympy, functions are usually just written as expressions containing symbolic variables (`symbols`).  Derivatives are calculated directly on the expression. Note that `diff(f, x)` can also be written as `f.diff(x)`, which might be easier to read.

```py
from sympy import symbols

x, y = symbols('x y')
P = (-3, -2)
# let f be a function of x and y:
f = x**3 + 3*x**2 - 9*x + y**3 - 12*y
# calculate the derivative of f towards x
f_x = f.diff(x) # so, f_x = 3*x**2 + 6*x - 9
# now, fill in the values into the derivative:
f_x.subs({x: P[0], y: P[1]}) # 0
```

Comment: I see, interesting!
Thank's for the help and explanation! :D